# What is a statement in coverage.py?

Tags: python, python-2.7, code-coverage, coverage.py

From http://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-4.3.4/cmd.html the coverage analysis report is done by:

```
$ coverage report -m
Name                      Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-------------------------------------------------------
my_program.py                20      4    80%   33-35, 39
my_module.py                 15      2    86%   8, 12
my_other_module.py           56      6    89%   17-23
-------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                        91     12    87%
```

But, what is a statement ("Stmts") in this tool?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I realized that statements are the number of lines of code including imports, class and function definitions (not counting the comments).

Answer (score 3):

`Stmts` is the number of total statements. For example, for the first line, 20 statements were executed, out of which 4 were missed, so 16 were covered:

```
16/20 = 0.8 (80%)
```

which matches the `80%` cover ratio in the table.